# Getting tabs to change classes when clicked for navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to change the class name for a tab when I click it.  I also want it to change back to the original one when I click a different tab.

I setup a very basic webpage just for testing.  The full code of the page is copied below.  Right now, this isn't working as it should, even though similar code was tested in JSfiddle and did work there.  Note that the design part is showing up fine.  Here are the two css rules that are part of this and the code for the full page follows:

```
.member_nav                 { float:left; margin-right:1px;height:65px;text-align:center;background-color:#636464;padding:0 20px 0 20px;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;color:#fff;line-height:60px;}
.member_nav_clicked                 { float:left; margin-right:1px;height:65px;text-align:center;background-color:#0099cc;padding:0 10px 0 10px;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;color:#fff;line-height:60px;}

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test Nav</title>
<link href="css_new/style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.member_nav').on('click', function() {
        $(this).addClass('member_nav_clicked').siblings().removeClass('member_nav_clicked');
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="member_nav">
    <a href="#">Nav 2</a>
</div>
<div class="member_nav">
<a href="#">Nav 3</a>
</div>
<div class="member_nav">
<a href="#">nav 4</a>
</div>
<div class="member_nav">
    <a href="#">Nav 5</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code I found that was causing everything to not work on the real site.  This was in the head right below the jQuery call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var popup_jq = jQuery.noConflict();
        popup_jq(document).ready(function() {
            popup_jq("#various1").fancybox({
                'titlePosition'     : 'inside',
                'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                'transitionOut'     : 'none',
                'showCloseButton'    : true
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: You need to include jQuery before you run your own code.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get it to work by updating to the latest jQuery, but it still only worked on the simplified version above.  It wasn't working when I threw it in with the rest of my code.  So I decided to do methodical debugging, and used the simple working version above as the start, and then began copying over the rest of the code from the real site piece by piece, until it broke.  I've posted the code above that caused it to break.  I took over an old project from someone else, so I don't know what this code does.  Any insights would be awesome!

Comment: Just an update that I finished bringing over all the code from the real site one by one.  I've confirmed that the script above is the culprit.  Everything else is exactly the same (I'm still even loading in the fancybox files), but it's working fine on the "new" page, but still not on the one that has the code above.  I'm hesitant to just leave it off since I don't know if it has an important reason for being there.